# Etwas »an einer Konferenz« tun

Tags: word-choice

In der *Neuen Züricher Zeitung* (NZZ) las ich heute die folgende Phrase:

> [...] sagte Mohammed bin Salman am Dienstag *an einer Konferenz* in Riad [...]

Statt der Präposition *an* würde ich *auf* oder *während* verwenden. Ist die Präposition *an* hier trotzdem richtig? Zu beachten ist, dass die NZZ eine Zeitung aus der Schweiz ist. Möglicherweise ist »an einer Konferenz« eine schweizerdeutsche Wendung?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Damit ist wohl gemeint, dass er das eben nicht *auf* der Konferenz am Rednerpult, sondern *nebenher*, z.B: bei einem Interview *an*läßlich der Konferenz gesagt hat.

Das ist trotzdem eine typisch Schweizer Formulierung, eine Zeitung in Deutschland hätte wohl geschrieben

> sagte der Kronprinz bei einem Wirtschaftsforum in Riad.

was der Spiegel auch anläßlich derselben Nachricht getan hat.

("am Rande einer Konferenz" oder "anläßlich einer Konferenz" wären wohl auch typisch Deutschland-deutsche Formulierungen für denselben Sachverhalt).

Comment: Ja mei, Schweiz bleibt Schweiz. Die Österreicher sagen auch "Mistplatz" wo der Preuße "Wertstoffsammelstelle" sagt.

Answer (score 5):

Ich denke, die in Deutschland üblichere Formulierung ist

> ...sagte am Rande einer Konferenz...

d. h. ein Teilnehmer der Konferenz sagte etwas zwar am Konferenzort aber außerhalb einer Präsentation oder eines Vortrags; dafür böten sich Formulierungen wie

> ...sagte auf/in/bei einer Konferenz...

an.